# How to add image in Django RadioSelect choices individually?

Tags: python, django

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms


BINDING = (
    ('1','Coil Bound Paperback'),
    ('2','Perfect Bound Paperback'),
    ('3','Saddle Stitch Paperback'),
)

class BindingForm(forms.Form):
    my_binding_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BINDING,widget 
=forms.RadioSelect())
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,render_to_response
from .forms import MyForm,BindingForm


def my_binding_view(request):
    form = BindingForm()
    return render(request,'base.html',{'binding_form':form})
```

**template.html**

```
{% for radio in binding_form %}
    <div class="myradio">
        {{ radio }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

'''But i want to add images to my choices so it would be shown in radioselect list,or that can be achieved in else method?'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass [`RadioSelect` and specify your own `option_template_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect) which will determine how each individual option is rendered:

```
class CustomRadioSelect(RadioSelect):
    option_template_name = 'myapp/radio_option_custom.html'

# Then use this widget in your form
class BindingForm(forms.Form):
    my_binding_choice = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BINDING, 
                                          widget=CustomRadioSelect())
```

Then supply a template `myapp/radio_option_custom.html` that renders each option the way you want. The default template is [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/input_option.html) so you can start with that and add whatever bits you need.