# Is there a way to make clickable images and select an that particular one?

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4, django-forms

I am working on a Graphical password authentication system using Django. During the registration process, I want to display few images , out of which the  user can select any one.
I want the selected image to be highlighted and also on the click of  submit button, I want that image to be stored in the database.

I had tried adding images in a button, but it did not work out. This is what i did

```
 <button name="b3" style="border:0px"><img src="/static/r9.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."></button>
```

Then I tried a different approach and used use-maps in HTML. But apparently that also seems to not work.

```
<img src="/static/r1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" name="img" alt="..." usemap="#imagemap">
```

the use map is defined as follows:

```
<map name="imagemap">
<area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" href="">
</map>
```

Can you please guide me what is the way to go forward with it since I am a newbie to Django. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use choices as RadioButton in Django and customize it.
[Here is a link that could help you get it with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49830480/how-to-add-image-in-django-radioselect-choices-individually)

Comment: I want to display images from my static folder. How do i do that? @ElayanHamamrah

Comment: you need to link each choice with the image from the static file.